# subprocess.run fails to call executable

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a Java program from within a Python program.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("ls") # ok
subprocess.run("whoami") # ok
subprocess.run("java --version") # not ok
```

I can run standard shell commands but *not* the Java executable. Why is that?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "syscall.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.run("java --version") # not ok
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java --version': 'java --version'
```

Comment: downvoting seems a bit drastic here ... this might be a duplicate, but it is very concise and has a good chance of a google search hit for this topic. Oh well ...

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass complete commands to `subprocess.run`. It accepts the parsed list of tokens that it uses to start the subprocess.

```
subprocess.run(["java", "--version"])
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

One way to bypass would be to pass `shell=True` to `run`, but that's [not recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).

You can also do the splitting automatically using [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)

```
subprocess.run(shlex.split("java --version"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`java --version` is a *shell* command, not an executable of its own. You need to pass `shell=True`.

```py
subprocess.run("java -version", shell=True)
```

By the way, `java` uses a single dash for everything, so I changed the command to `java -version`.

Example output:

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run("java -version", shell=True)
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
CompletedProcess(args='java -version', returncode=0)
```